# css3 transition

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы сначала цвет поменялся на зеленый, а затем спустя такой же интервал стал синим, при этом не отводя курсора от блока. Заранее спасибо:)

```css
#s {
  width: 20%;
  height: 10em;
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 5s;
}

#s:hover {
  background: green;
  transition: background 5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="s"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам поможет `@keyframes`:

```css
 #s{
   width: 20%;
   height: 10em;
   background: red;
 } 
 
 #s:hover{
   animation: bg 5s linear forwards;       
 }
 
 @keyframes bg {
  0% {background: red;}
  50% {background: green;}
  100% {background: blue;}
 }
```

```html
<div id='s'></div>
```

Comment: Ну вот, ты первый))

Comment: @Qwertiy случайно зашел, пока проект пересобирается на дженкинсе =)

Comment: @Qwertiy, какая разница кто первый если ваши ответы неправильные? =)

Answer (score 6):

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: red;
}

div:hover {
  animation: bg 5s linear forwards 1;
}

@keyframes bg {
    0% { background-color: red;   }
   50% { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: blue;  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102300/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy-css3-transition).

Answer (score 6):

Вот решение при помощи transition и без доп элементов:

```css
#s{
   width: 20%;
   height: 10em;
   background: linear-gradient(red -1000px, red 0, green 10000px, blue 20000px);
   transition: 5s;
   background-size: 100% 21000px;
 } 
 
#s:hover{
 background-position: 20% -20000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='s'></div>
```

Comment: от таких споров и соревнований только польза, если она выливается только в код. (+) Спорьте ребята, спорьте!

Answer (score 4):

Строго говоря ответы основанные на свойстве `animation` являются неверными - в вопросе ясно сказано что нужно использовать `transition`.

```css
#s {
  width: 20%;
  height: 10em;
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 5s;
}

#s:hover {
  background: green;
}

#d {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 5s 5s;
}

#d:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="s">
  <div id="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы забиваете гвозди шуруповёртом если Вас попросят? Даже если у Вас есть молоток?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вспомнил, как я тебе говорил про микроскоп и d3 :)))  Константин, забыл про мою тему с красным шариком? Очень хочу твоего ответа с оптимизированным кодом JS

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov на мой взгляд, лучше будем смотреться, если уменьшить время анимации и задержки

Comment: @StrangerintheQ всё равно, не упускай из вида, вдруг осенит

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, если в ТЗ написано - шуроповертом, то да. Вы же не знаете в какой среде попытаются применить ваше решение. Может быть там `animation` не поддерживается, а `transition` - в полный рост.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov возможен и другой вариант, что ТС кроме `transition` ни о чём другом и не слышал или забыл. Вот ребята и подсказали ему своими ответами.  Зеленая галочка косвенно подтверждает это :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, вероятно так и есть. Однако разве не интереснее решить вопрос с ограничениями, а не тиражировать очевидное решение?

Comment: @Согласен. Поэтому я вам поставил плюс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, неллохо. Правда в ff есть артефакты.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3GA7.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не, что-то не так...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, `background-size: 100% 21000px;` решает. Что за бред? )))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я там поправил немного. Проблема исчезла.